# Soap Call keeps loading and gives no response at all

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soap-client

I', trying to do a call to an the webservice with the following code:

```
$soap_uri = 'https://ato-webservices.**********.nl/***/V20131016';

$this->client = new \SoapClient($soap_uri, array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => true,
    'exception' => true,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'login' => "usern*me",
    'password' => "passw*rd"
));
```

After that I want to call the action 'getAccessToken' with

```
$params = array(
    'userName' => 'robinhoedjes@**********.nl',
    'password' => 'passw*rd'
)

$result = $this->client->GetAccessToken(
    $params
;
```

But it keeps loading in the browser on this call. I can wait for half an hour but it keeps loading.

I can call the function list without any problems.

```
var_dump($this->client->__getFunctions());
```

Comment: I would recommend to test your webservice with soap ui client first. First make sure whether your webservice is in active state or not and how it is responding. Then try to make your php client. As often we make silly mistakes while creating client or due to version or software limitation we spoil our time to resolve these issues..

Comment: With soapUI the client is responding within milliseconds so the webservice is active. But my php client just hang of the soapcall, there is no response at all, even the timeout is not trigger as the page is still loading after half an hour or so.

Comment: am also facing same issue, SOAP UI gives result in a second and my code keep loading and going to gateway timeout